# Dropping assumption from Vitali-Porter Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

The statement of the Vitali-Porter Theorem is as follows:

> Let $G$ be a domain and let $\{f_n\}$ be a locally uniformly bounded sequence of holomorphic functions on $G$. Assume there is a set $A\subseteq G$, which has limit point in $G$ and that $\{f_n\}$ converges (pointwise) on $A$. Then $\{f_n\}$ converges locally uniformly on $G$.

Given the assumptions of the Vitali-Porter Theorem, but assume $A$ does not have an accumulation point in $G$. Show that there exists a locally uniformly bounded sequence of holomorphic functions $\{f_n\}$ in $G$ such that $\{f_n\}$ converges for all $z \in A$, but $\{f_n\}$ does not converge locally
uniformly on $G$.

Any hints on how to construct such a sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, for any $A$ as above, you can find a holomorphic function $f$ on $G$ with zero set precisely $A$; then obviously $z+f(z), z$ are different functions that coincide on $A$ and the sequence alternating them, $f_{2n}=z, f_{2n+1}=z+f(z)$ will do

Comment: Great example thanks! I assume local uniform boundedness comes from the fact that $f$ is holomorphic on G?

Comment: Yes and note that the hypothesis implies you always have normally converging subsequences (from any given subsequence) so in a way that's the best you can do as failure mode goes - you can obviously tinker a little with approximations but essentially you need a normal family with at least two limit functions, both taking same values on the given set)

Answer (score 1):

Take $f_n(z)=e^{in\pi}z$ on the unit disk so $|f_n(z)|\le 1$ and $f_n(0)=0\to 0$ but clearly $f_n(z)$ does not converge for $z\neq 0$.

Comment: This is an example for $A={0}$ right? Its very elegant!